# how can i remove the extra space in my output?

Tags: python, arrays

> I'm using the following code to get the mean of an array made with user input .

```
import numpy as np
```

n, p = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

lst = []

d = (n*p)/2

for i in range(int(d)):

```
ele = input().split()

lst.append(ele)
if len(lst) == (d):
    break
```

x_arr = np.array(lst)

x_arr.reshape(n, p)

x_arr_new = x_arr.astype(float)

y = x_arr_new.mean(axis=1)
print(y)

> for example i Input this :

> 3 2

> 1 2

> 1 0.5

> 1 0.3

> the OUTPUT that i have is this :

> `[1.5  0.75 0.65]`

> while the OUTPUT that i want is this :

> `[1.5 0.75 0.65]`

> Notice the difference in spaces between the first and second OUTPUT after the first number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as I wanted the answer to be in the form of a list without two spaces after the first number, I did the following

```
import numpy as np

n, p = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

lst = []

d = (n*p)/2

for i in range(int(d)):
    ele = input().split()
    lst.append(ele)
    if len(lst) == (d):
        break

x_arr = np.array(lst)

x_arr.reshape(n, p)

x_arr_new = x_arr.astype(float)

y = x_arr_new.mean(axis=1)

k = []

for t in y:
   k.append(t)

k_arr = np.array(str(k))

b = ''.join(str(k).split(','))

print(b)
```

> the input will be

> 3 2

> 1 3

> 1 0.5

===========

> the OUTPUT will be

> [2.0 0.65 0.75]

> without any space

> of course I'm a beginner so forgive me for the crude code

Answer (score 0):

Use just have to create `custom string object` instead of calling inbuilt `numpy  __str__` method return string object. For that use have to add this line of code :

```
y = [str(i) for i in y]
```

---

**`FINAL CODE`**

```
import numpy as np
n, p = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
lst = []
d = (n*p)/2
for i in range(int(d)):
    ele = input().split()
    lst.append(ele)

x_arr = np.array(lst)
x_arr.reshape(n, p)
x_arr_new = x_arr.astype(float)
y = x_arr_new.mean(axis=1) 
y = [str(i) for i in y]
print(' '.join(y))
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work as i wanted, because i needed the result to be an array, while your solution gave me a custom string as you have suggested

Comment: @lil2big just check the code and let me know any other issue

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work